# Using DECLARE in stored procedure for Oracle results in syntax error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "SYNC_EMPLOYEES_WITH_HR" (
  EMPLOYEE_NUMBER IN NUMBER
) AS

Declare middle_initial varchar(200);
Declare first_initial varchar(200);
Declare last_initial varchar(200);
Declare TERMINATION_DATE Date;
Declare network_Id varchar(200);

BEGIN    



    select @first_initial = first_name,@middle_initial =middle_initial,@last_initial =last_name, @network_Id = network_id, @TERMINATION_DATE = termination_date from human_resources where employee_number = EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;



    update Employee set first_name = @first_initial,middle_initial = @middle_initial,last_name = @last_initial,user_id = @network_Id, inactive_date = @TERMINATION_DATE where employee_number = EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;

END
```

I do not have access to Oracle PL/SQL so I need to hand the code to the DBA and he tells me there is a syntax error (that's all it said).

I do not see the syntax error. Can anyone help me? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: That looks like Microsoft T-SQL, a completely different language I'm afraid. There are examples in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html), but to start with, the `declare` keyword begins a declaration block in PL/SQL (similar to `begin`), variable names can't include the `@` character, and `select` requires an `into` clause unless it's part of a cursor.

Comment: Also, `where employee_number = EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` is going to be true for every row, isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is not valid syntax in Oracle as:

- `DECLARE` begins a the variable declaration section of a PL/SQL block (it is not used before each variable);
- `@` is not a valid prefix for variables.
- You need to use `SELECT value1, value2 INTO variable1, variable2 FROM ...` rather than `SELECT variable1 = column1, variable2 = column2 FROM ...`.
- `where employee_number = EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` is like `WHERE 1 = 1` as `employee_number` is taken from the local SQL scope on both sides of the operation rather than having one from the local SQL scope and one from the outer PL/SQL scope; you need to name your PL/SQL variable differently to the column name.

You can simplify it all down to a single `MERGE` statement:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SYNC_EMPLOYEES_WITH_HR (
  P_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER IN EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER%TYPE
) AS
BEGIN    
  MERGE INTO Employee dst
  USING (
    SELECT employee_number,
           first_name,
           middle_initial,
           last_name,
           network_id, 
           termination_date
    FROM   human_resources
    WHERE  employee_number = P_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
  ) src
  ON (dst.employee_number = src.employee_number)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET first_name       = src.first_name,
        middle_initial   = src.middle_initial,
        last_name        = src.last_name,
        network_id       = src.network_id, 
        termination_date = src.termination_date;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RLsJ7NpB)